# NetSuite Customization - Select ItemFulfillment "Packages" as a List/Record as a Custom Record field

Tags: netsuite

I am attempting to create a custom record that has a field called "Box". I need this field to be a reference to the "Package(s)" in an ItemFulfillment.
When I go to add this field as type "List/Record" I do not see anything that looks like it would be a "Package" or an "ItemFulfillment Package" in the selectable list of List/Record.

Any help in this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this can be done.  Under List/Record, you could choose "Transaction". This should allow you to link to the Fulfillment. From there, you'll be able to reference some of the fields on the Fulfillment. However, I don't think you'll find the "box" field.

Comment: This is what I have seen.  I have already linked the itemFulfillment as my parent and was just trying to link into the boxes to add some additional functionality that I need.  Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: You are correct in that it can not be done.  Packages is a sublist to the item shipment and not a custom record.  This makes things more difficult and am thinking about approaching what I need to do a different way.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented packages (boxes) as a custom record, with "package items" (items in each package) as a child record of that.  By doing so, we could track which items went in each package, as well as do searches of the packages.  We duplicate weight and tracking number in the standard sublist, just in case anyone wants it, but we have that in our package custom record.